# Count chars difference between two strings

Tags: strings, scala, edit-distance

Given two strings with the same length, we check how many chars on the same positions are different. For example: ABCD and ABBD should return 1. Here is a link to a [gist with tests](https://gist.github.com/HeeL/97acff788b5eb524564b), to have a better understanding of what I'm building.
Here is my solution:

```
object Hamming {

  def compute(str1: String, str2: String):Int = {
    if (str1.length != str2.length)
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Strings have different length")
    (0 to str1.length - 1).filter(i => str1(i) != str2(i)).size
  }

}
```

Comment: It's vaguely entertaining to see an Exercism question here.

Answer (score 4):

How about this variant?

```
object Hamming {

    def apply(a: String, b: String): Int = if (a.length != b.length) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(s"Strings a=$a and b=$b have different length.")
    } else a.zip(b).count {
        case (charA, charB) => charA != charB
    }

}
```

The `zip`-function does create a new collection of tuples with two corresponding chars side by side in every tuple. `(Char, Char)` 
The `count`-function counts the number of elements for which a boolean evaluation function, passed as an argument, returns `true`. This should work not only for characters, because it uses pattern matching. Also if there are two arguments of the same type (e.g. for comparison) and I cannot further specify what they are, then I like to name them `a` and `b`.
I cannot tell if this solution is faster than yours, but I don't think there will be a significant difference.

P.S.:

- I see the function is named `compute`. Thats really general and abstract. I named it `apply`. It can be called like this: `Hamming("Alice", "Bob")`
- Look at what I did with the brackets.
- If you would like to use the function for other sequences than characters you can change the snippet to this:

  ```
  def apply(a: Seq[_], b: Seq[_]): Int = if (a.size != b.size) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Parameters have different length.")
  } else a.zip(b).count {
      case (charA, charB) => charA != charB
  }
  ```

Answer (score 3):

Note of warning: I haven't done Scala in a while. The style may have changed, or I may have never known the right one, so I could be wrong.

It looks good, except for two things:

1. Please, put brackets around one-line `if`s. It makes things much easier to keep track of in the long run, even if you don't need it now. Before you say "this is just a project to learn the language", if you get into good habits now, you won't have to break bad ones later.
2. You have a pair of newlines that have no purpose after the beginning and before the end of the `object` definition

Aside from that, it looks good! I like the 'algorithm' you chose to use; it's actually quite clever and easy to understand.

Comment: About if block, I know its a good practice to wrap one liners in javascript. I'm not sure about Scala, I've seen a lot of good code where people didn't do this, so I picked up that style. Maybe someone will have something to say about this case

Comment: @HeeL It's generally a better idea, for lots of reasons -- you see people talking about it in Java, C#, Javascript -- pretty much every language where you can wrap brackets around `if` blocks, it's said you should. I'd assume the same extends to Scala.